# Ethminer on Ubuntu giving Error with Intel HD Graphics 520

Tags: ethminer, ubuntu

I am using Ethminer v0.18.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I have Intel HD Graphics 520 integrated GPU. When I run `./ethminer -G -P stratum1+tcp://x84eAFEa93b0304A1e0Ef5ABE57e07fE7932eCE19E@us1.ethpool.org:33330` I get the error `Unrecognized platform Intel(R) OpenCL HD Graphics Error: No usable mining devices found` 
I wanted to try Ethereum mining but due to the above error, I can not do so.

Comment: Maybe this link can help you : https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherMining/comments/lv21va/pool_mining_ethereum_with_intel_integrated/

Answer (score 0):

Intel support was added in 2020<sup>1</sup>, but as of now the last binary release is from 2019, so you'll have to build from source. Clone or download the master branch, but before you try to build you'll have to fix the Hunter package manager issue<sup>2</sup> by replacing the contents of `cmake/Hunter/config.cmake` with:

```
hunter_config(Boost VERSION 1.66.0)
hunter_config(
    Boost
    VERSION 1.66.0_new_url
    SHA1 f0b20d2d9f64041e8e7450600de0267244649766
    URL https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.66.0/source/boost_1_66_0.tar.gz
)
```

Then build according to [the build guide](https://github.com/ethereum-mining/ethminer/blob/master/docs/BUILD.md) but with `cmake -DETHASHCUDA=0 ..` to disable cuda. Using the built version of ethminer, it should recognize your Intel GPU.

Credits:

[1](https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherMining/comments/lv21va/pool_mining_ethereum_with_intel_integrated/)

[2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/652841/boost-continually-fails-to-download-while-using-cmake-for-ethminer)